# How to access a prototype function in a array loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I've the following object structure (just a sample object):

```
var Sample = function Sample (name)
{ this.init(name); };

Sample.prototype.init = function (name)
{ this.name_ = name; }

Sample.prototype.getName = function ()
{ return 'The name is '+this.name_; }

var obj = new Sample();
console.log ( obj.getName() );
```

When I do something like above it works well and print inside console as it has to be. But when I have a array collection I can't access the `getName()` function. For exemple:

```
var biblio = [];

biblio.push(new Sample('A'));
biblio.push(new Sample('B'));
biblio.push(new Sample('C'));
biblio.push(new Sample('D'));

for ( var i = 0; i < biblio.lenght; i++ )
{ console.log ( biblio[i].getName() ); }
```

For the case above, I always get `undefined`. But outside of the `for` usign something like `biblio[0].getName()` it works well.

How can I access the function of a object in a for loop?

Comment: typo in `lenght`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just correct this `biblio.length` and It will work according to you!.

```js
var Sample = function Sample (name)
{ this.init(name); };

Sample.prototype.init = function (name)
{ this.name_ = name; }

Sample.prototype.getName = function ()
{ return 'The name is '+this.name_; }

var obj = new Sample();
console.log ( obj.getName() );

var biblio = [];

biblio.push(new Sample('A'));
biblio.push(new Sample('B'));
biblio.push(new Sample('C'));
biblio.push(new Sample('D'));

for ( var i = 0; i < biblio.length; i++ )
{ console.log ( biblio[i].getName() ); }
```